# Is it possible to create a validation with multiple regex pattern using regula?

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, regula

I need to check given text is validate as a wep key. So I need to check all below regular expressions for one field. Is there a way to do that with [regula](https://github.com/vivin/regula/wiki)?

```
^(([0-9A-Fa-f]{10})|)$

^(([\\s\\S]{5})|)$

^(([0-9A-Fa-f]{26})|)$

^(([\\s\\S]{13})|)$

^(([0-9A-Za-z]{58})|)$

^(([0-9A-Fa-f]{24})|)$

[\\s\\S]
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you don't really want to check those regexes. Most of them don't make much sense, or they overlap a lot. And who is using WEP these days, anyway?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether a string is a) composed entirely of hexadecimal digits and b) exactly 0, 10, 24, 26 or 58 characters in length (although I don't get what you want with 24 digits), then you can either use

```
^[0-9a-fA-F]*$
```

and assert that the length of the match is exactly 0, 10, 24, 26 or 58. Or you can do it in a single regex:

```
^(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{10}|[0-9a-fA-F]{24}|[0-9a-fA-F]{26}|[0-9a-fA-F]{58})?$
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Tim's answer :

```
^(([0-9A-Fa-f]{10})|)$
```

You realize that this matches also nothing right? And you have this in each and every regex? Why?

Then you have `[\\s\\S]` which matches everything. It is unclear to me and possibly all others what you are trying to achieve here. Please edit your question.

Comment: Hi, sorry I'am new at regex. Can you explain why `^(([0-9A-Fa-f]{10})|)$` matches nothing?

Comment: Because the expression `^(([0-9A-Fa-f]{10})|)$` says to match at the beginning (`^`), then match _either_ the expression `([0-9A-Fa-f]{10})` **OR** the expression between the "or" symbol (`|`) and  the closing parentheses (`)`), which is a zero length string, then finally to match at the end (`$`). It will thus match beginning (`^`), nothing, ending (`$`).